# VsCode Merge Conflicts with Spring Boot Tools

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

So I'm working on a project where everyone is using Spring Boot Tools and I'm using VsCode. We're using the same formatter, however when I commit an entire merge conflict is created with an entire file.

I did the diff between them and it seems the reasons is that VSCode is placing ^M at the end of each line, whereas Spring Boot Tools isn't?

I.e

```
 +^I^ISettlement settlement = null;^M   
 +^I^Isettlement = schedulingService.updateSettlement(id, identifiers);^M   
 +^I^Iif (settlement == null) {^M   
 +^I^I^Ireturn ResponseEntity.status(404).build();^M    
 +^I^I}^M   
 +^I^IString etag = Helper.getEtag(settlement);^M   
 +^I^IresponseHeaders.set("ETag", etag);^M  
 +^I^Ireturn ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(settlement);^M   
 +^I}^M
```

vs

```
+ ^I^ISettlement settlement = null;
+ ^I^Isettlement = schedulingService.updateSettlement(id, identifiers);
+ ^I^Iif (settlement == null) {
+ ^I^I^Ireturn ResponseEntity.status(404).build();
+ ^I^I}
+ ^I^IString etag = Helper.getEtag(settlement);
+ ^I^IresponseHeaders.set("ETag", etag);
+ ^I^Ireturn ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(settlement);
+ ^I}
```

That is what I get from a diff between the two.

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following configurations in **Settings.json** and see if it solves your question:

```
"merge-conflict.codeLens.enabled": false,
"merge-conflict.decorators.enabled": false,
```

Comment: @dxm324. May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it here. We can work together to figure it out.